# Export data to file docx, node.js and react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I use node.Js and react Js, I want to put the data into the docx file just like in the picture, I have a docxtemplater reference but it's not free, someone please help me

[image]

Comment: its look like excel, but you told docx, tell what you need exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Python. Create a Python script an call it from NodeJS. Python have some libraries for `docx` manipulation. The one that you can use is `python-docx-template`.

**STEP 1:**

Create a Python script that will work for you.

**STEP 2**

You can use `spawn` module to call Python script from NodeJS.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const python_script = spawn('python', ['relative_path_to_python_script']);
python_script.stdin.write('You can send some inputs to Python script here');
python_script.stdin.end();
python_script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  // data - output from Python script
  // This will execute after the Python script finishes
});
python_script.stderr.on('data', (error) => {
  // This will execute if Python script throws an error
});
```